# Melhor maneira de armazenar um JSON

Tags: javascript

Olá, recebo um json nesse modelo de uma requisição

```
{  
   "alunos":[  
      {  
         "ID":"1",
         "Nome":"Pedro",
      },
      {  
         "ID":"2",
         "Nome":"Lucas",
      },
      {  
         "ID":"3",
         "Nome":"Joana",
      }
   ]
}
```

Gostaria de um exemplo bom de como armazenar ele em uma variavel local, para uso posterior, array seria uma boa escolha ?

Comment: Olha, não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas não seria bom utilizar por exemplo: var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString); ???

Comment: É uma boa maneira?

Comment: Na verdade, não vejo outra! Desta forma, você já transforma a string num objeto e faz o que quer com ele. Entende? Só faria essa alteração: var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString) || {}; 
Pois se não conseguir converter, ele retorna um obj vazio...

Comment: Qual é a duvida concreta que tem ? Ou o que não está a conseguir fazer com essa informação ? O que o @DiegoSantos disse já resolve o problema e guarda a informação num objeto que é o ideal em quase todos os casos.

Comment: pra salvar em obj eu sempre tenho que escrever obj, ou posso colocar outra coisa ?

Comment: Isso é só o nome da variável. Pode ter o nome que quiser.

Comment: Ok obrigado, dúvida resolvida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma seria a conversão para um objeto javascript.

A maioria dos navegadores suporta JSON.parse(), que está definida na ECMA-262 5ª edição (a especificação em que o JavaScript é baseado):

```
var json = '{"teste":1,"teste2":true}',
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Seguem algumas referencias que vale a pena consultar para entender melhor como funciona o parse do json no javascript:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc836458(v=vs.94).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc836459(v=vs.94).aspx